# Map route parameters to model in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an action with the following annotation,

```
[HttpGet("update/{hash}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromQuery]Model model)
{
    // I need to use from model.Hash
    return Ok();
}
```

In addition, I have a simple model like below:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Hash { get; set; }
}
```

The model binder is not working, because that's clear the hash is not a queryString like ?hash=[value], it's an id.

I can not use another parameter to bind it like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(string hash)
```

because I have a validator for my model.

Is there any way in which I can bind **hash** to **Hash** my property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can able to bind the route parameter to the model property by using `[FromRoute(Name = "hash")]` as shown in below.

```
public class Model
{
   [FromRoute(Name = "hash")]
   public string Hash { get; set; }
}
```

Refer [this Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#model-binding-for-http-get-requests)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `[FromQuery]` if you aren't getting anything from the query.

You can replace that attribute with `[FromRoute]`.

If you change `{hash}` to `{Hash}` in the route pattern, you can leave `Model` alone instead of having to add an attribute to it to override the name to lowercase.

```
[HttpGet("update/{Hash}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromRoute]Model model)
{
    return Ok();
}

public class Model
{
    public string Hash { get; set; }
}
```